# SQL Server : calculate running time using Login and / or Logout

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that gives me the total hours a user is logged in. I need to modify this so that it gives me a running total without waiting until the user logs out to calculate. Thanks for taking a look.

This is what I have

```
SELECT 
    AGENTID,
SUM (DATEDIFF(ss, LOGON,LOGOFF)/3600.0)AS HOURS
FROM 
    ASDM.DBO.AGENTLOGIN
WHERE 
    LOGON > '2015-10-02'AND LOGON < '2015-10-03'
GROUP BY 
    AGENTID
```

Comment: So LOGOFF is null? Replace it with the current time should work, like this: `ISNULL(LOGOFF, GETDATE())` (assuming you are using non-UTC dates, otherwise use `GETUTCDATE`)

Comment: @DavidG Great answer. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `LOGOFF` value is going to be null when the user hasn't yet logged out, you can replace that with the current time instead by using the [`IFNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

```
SELECT 
    AGENTID,
    SUM (DATEDIFF(ss, LOGON,ISNULL(LOGOFF, GETDATE()))/3600.0)AS HOURS
FROM 
    ASDM.DBO.AGENTLOGIN
WHERE 
    LOGON > '2015-10-02'AND LOGON < '2015-10-03'
GROUP BY 
    AGENTID
```